# Misunderstanding with indices in covariance and contravariance

Tags: calculus, tensors, semi-riemannian-geometry

I am getting confused with naming things covariant or contravariant. I am reading [Barret O Neil's book on semi riemannian geometry with applications to relativity](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Semi_Riemannian_Geometry_With_Applicatio/CGk1eRSjFIIC?hl=en&gbpv=0), and I need some help with the indices.

On page 35 it says that a tensor field

\begin{equation}
A:\mathcal{X}^*(M)^r \times \mathcal{X}(M)^s\rightarrow\mathcal{F}(M)
\end{equation}

A is a multilinear machine which when fed $r$ one-forms $\theta^1,...,\theta^r$ and $s$ vector fields $X_1,...,X_s$, produces a real-valued function

\begin{equation}
f=A(\theta^1,...,\theta^r,X_1,...,X_s)\in\mathcal{F}(M),
\end{equation}

so I see that a one-form is some object that has an upper index.

However, on page 37 it says that a tensor of type $(0,s)$ is said to be covariant (lower index), such as real-valued functions and one-forms, while a tensor of type $(r,0)$ is said to be contravariant (upper index) like vector fields. So this tells that a one-form should have a lower index.

Also, on page 38 it says that $\alpha^1,...,\alpha^r\in T_pM^*$ are one-forms because they live in the dual space, while the vector fields are $x_1,...,x_s\in T_pM$, but on page 39 again the one-form is $\theta=\sum\theta_k dx^k$ (with lower index) and the vector field $X=\sum X^i\partial_i$ (with upper index).

I guess it has to do with whether you refer to the component or the element of the basis, but I would like some confirmation because this seems rather non-trivial but no clarification is made throughout the book, so I might be missing something. If that is the case, then why isn't it more useful to write directly the elements of the basis $A(dx^1,...,dx^r,\partial_1,...,\partial_{s})
$ instead of $A(\theta^1,...,\theta^r,X_1,...,X_s)$, which is a notation usually employed to refer to the components?

Comment: I think you are almost there. Take, say, the coordinate transformation in 2d between Cartesian and polar coordinates and work out using the chain rule how the basis vector fields $\partial_x,\partial_y$ and $\partial_r\,,\frac{1}{r}\partial_\theta$ must transform. Then take a vector field $\mathbf{a}=a^x\,\partial_x+a^y\partial_y$ and write it in polar coordinates $\mathbf{a}=a^r\,\partial_r+a^\theta\frac{1}{r}\,\partial_\theta\,.$ You will see inevitably that the components of $\mathbf{a}$ are contravariant and the basis vectors covariant.

Comment: The same logic you can apply to the pairing $\theta(X)$ which is a scalar that should not depend on the choice of the coordinates. Components of $X$ are contravariant, hence, components of $\theta$ must be covariant.

Comment: To answer your last question: The notation $A(dx^1,...,dx^r,\partial_1,...,\partial_{s})$ is not useful. The tensor $A$ allows as arguments identical forms, and identical vector fields in different slots which your notation seems to forbid. In other words: $A(\theta,...,\theta,X,...,X)$ must be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion lies in the context. In
$$f=A(\theta^1,\theta^2,...,\theta^r,X_1,...,X_s)\in\mathcal{F}(M),$$
the meaning of the "$1$" in $\theta^1$ is "the first one-form of a list of one-forms", the meaning of the "$2$" in $\theta^2$ is "the second one-form of a list of one-forms" and so on.

While in
$$\theta=\sum\theta_k dx^k$$
the meaning is "the component $\theta_k$ is a covariant quantity" and "the basis element $dx^k$ is a contravariant quantity".

Comment: So, $\theta^1$ would be $\theta^1=\sum\theta_k^1dx^k$ and $\theta^2=\sum\theta_k^2dx^k$, right?

Comment: @tupoliedro right